# action keyup after the third charecter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi could someone help me figure out how to stop a function running until a specific number of characters are pressed?

currently using the following function:

```
$('input#q').keyup
```

this works as soon as you press any key...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this should start firing code after 3 letters have been added:

**[Live Example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/XczT8/)**

JavaScript

```
$('input#q').keyup( function() {
   if( this.value.length < 4 ) return;
   /* code to run below */
   $('#output').val(this.value); 
});
```

HTML

```
<input id="q" />
<br /><br />
<input id="output"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

you could do :

```
$('input#q').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val().length > 3)
  {
    //do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store the characters in a string variable each time a key is pressed and then run a conditional statement to check the length of the variable. If it's equal to three, run whatever function

Comment: Note that the field in question is an input field, so the browser is already "storing the characters in a string" - the value of the input!

Comment: Yeah, I missed the input was being targeted in the original code and thought it might be some kind of discrete detection - I'll look closer next time :P

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll probably need to take into account the way focus changes. Do you want to clear the counter when the field is newly focused or not?  You should also decide whether you're counting characters actually added to the field, or instead if you want to could actual discrete key presses - a "shift" key press, for example, won't add any characters, but it's a key being pressed.

Anyway it'd probably be something like this:

```
$(function() {
  var keyCount = 0;
  $('#q').keyup(function() { // "keypress" to count characters
    if (++keyCount === 3) {
      // do the thing
    }
  })
  .focus(function() {
    keyCount = 0; // if this is what you want
  });
});
```

If you're counting the "keypress" event instead of "keyup", you might want to count the actual length of the text field value rather than trying to count events.

Answer (score 0):

How's about:

```
var c = 0;
('input#q').keyup( function() {
   c++;
   if (c >= 3) {
      startGame();
   }
} );
```